# Как поставить скрипт на постоянное повторение через определенное время в минутах?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Я только начал изучать Python из-за необходимости вести рассылку в Telegram. У меня есть такой скрипт, но он заканчивается после отправки. Можете подсказать, что мне изменить, чтобы он повторялся через определенное время не закрываясь? Спасибо большое. Извините, если что не так спрашиваю

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait, BadRequest, Flood, InternalServerError
from time import sleep
from sys import stderr, exit
from loguru import logger
from dotenv import dotenv_values
from msvcrt import getch
from os import system



def clear(): return system('cls')


config = dotenv_values()
SESSION_NAME = config['session_name']
API_ID = int(config['api_id'])
API_HASH = config['api_hash']

logger.remove()
logger.add(stderr,
           format='<white>{time:HH:mm:ss}</white> | '
                  '<level>{level: <8}</level> | '
                  '<cyan>{line}</cyan> - '
                  '<white>{message}</white>')

app = Client(SESSION_NAME, API_ID, API_HASH)

with open('otc.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    otc_list = [row.strip() for row in file]

msg_text = open('msg_text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()


def send_message_otc(current_otc):
    for _ in range(3):
        try:
            with app:
                app.send_message(current_otc, msg_text)

        except FloodWait as error:
            logger.info(f'{current_otc} | FloodWait: {error.x}')
            sleep(error.x)

        except Flood:
            pass

        except BadRequest as error:
            logger.error(f'{current_otc} | {error}')

        except InternalServerError as error:
            logger.error(f'{current_otc} | {error}')

        except Exception as error:
            logger.error(f'{current_otc} | {error}')

        else:
            logger.success(f'{current_otc} | The message was successfully sent')
            return

    with open('errors_send_message.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(f'{current_otc}\n')


def join_chat_otc(current_otc):
    for _ in range(3):
        try:
            with app:
                app.join_chat(current_otc)

        except FloodWait as error:
            logger.info(f'{current_otc} | FloodWait: {error.x}')
            sleep(error.x)

        except Flood:
            pass

        except BadRequest as error:
            logger.error(f'{current_otc} | {error}')

        except InternalServerError as error:
            logger.error(f'{current_otc} | {error}')

        except Exception as error:
            logger.error(f'{current_otc} | {error}')

        else:
            logger.success(f'{current_otc} | Successfully logged into the chat')
            return

    with open('errors_join_chat.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(f'{current_otc}\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_action = int(input('Enter your action '
                            '(1 - join chats from .txt; '
                            '2 - send message in chats from .txt): '))

    clear()

    for current_otc in otc_list:
        if user_action == 1:
            join_chat_otc(current_otc)

        elif user_action == 2:
            send_message_otc(current_otc)

    logger.success('Работа успешно завершена!')
    print('\nPress Any Key To Exit..')
    getch()
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(MailSendFunc, 'interval', minutes=60, jitter = 1)
scheduler.start()
keyboard.wait() # Block forever, like while True.
```

Другой вариант запуска по расписанию. Эти строки ставим в самом конце.
А где-то в начале ставим

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler # запуск по расписанию
```

Как установить и использовать смотреть тут: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html

Но конкретно в вашем случае я бы рекомендовал создать в системном планировщике (Task Scheduler) задачу, которая будет вызывать ваш скрипт раз в час. В этом случае вы будете меньше зависеть от ошибок, которые не отловили.

Comment: большое спасибо ща помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум два варианта (оба не идеальны). Выбирайте:

1. Ставим бесконечный цикл

   `while True: \n userFunc() \n time.sleep(60)`
   (не знаю как отформатировать)
2. Создаем в системном планировщике (Task Scheduler) задачу, которая будет вызывать ваш скрипт раз в минуту.

*Но, подозреваю, вам нужно асинхронное выполнение.*

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Мне нужно запустить рассылку, затем через час, затем еще через час, и чтобы так продолжалось до бесконечности. Мне подойдет ваш первый вариант? Его поставить в самый конец скрипта?